# symfony2 get field from controller without getting whole entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity

I am having an issue. Am new to symfony2 and I am trying to get a field of a  repository in my controller without getting all of it. I tried with the findAll() and it works 'except that am getting all the fields'.

Here is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace Extranet\RepportsBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class UtilisateurController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Retrieves utilisateurs name(called entite)
     * 
     * @Route("/utilisateur", name="extranet_repports_utilisateur")
     * @Template("ExtranetRepportsBundle:Utilisateur:index.html.twig")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        // $entity = $em->getRepository("ExtranetUtilisateurBundle:Utilisateur")->findAll(array());
        $entity = $em->getRepository("ExtranetUtilisateurBundle:Utilisateur")
                     ->createQueryBuilder(
                        'SELECT u.name FROM ExtranetUtilisateurBundle:Utilisateur u ORDER BY u.name ASC'
                     )
                     ->getResult();
        ;

        var_dump($entity);die();

        return array('entity' => $entity);
    }
}

// $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
// $query = $em->createQuery(
//     'SELECT p
//     FROM AcmeStoreBundle:Product p
//     WHERE p.price > :price
//     ORDER BY p.price ASC'
// )->setParameter('price', '19.99');

// $products = $query->getResult();
```

I am trying to get only the username from the repository and the commented code below is the example from the symfony book

Thanks for your help

Comment: as most of people are english speaking , if you could translate the part in French, it may help people to understand what you're trying to do. Also by "field", do you mean "one record"  (i.e one user ) ?

Comment: hi @allan.simon. Sorry for the french part. I think the only french word if am not wrong is "Utilisateur" which means user. And by field i mean to fetch only the name from the user table but i want all records. It is to build a list of all members and I dont want to retrieve all of their information just to print their names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify your properties in `select()` method of query builder which you want to select

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entity = $em->getRepository("ExtranetUtilisateurBundle:Utilisateur");
$result=  $entity->createQueryBuilder('u')
                 ->select('u.name')
                 ->orderBy('u.name')
                 ->getQuery()
                 ->getArrayResult();
```

Comment: that was great and so fast. Just a little typo in getQuery but just awesome.
Thanks